# how to write this logic in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table with 3 columns and a new record is generated for every 2 minutes.

ID: An ID is generated for each and every record in an order(in chronological order along with date and time stamp)

Time: Date and time stamp (which is exactly runs for every 2 minutes)

Flag: 0 or 1 (1 means good 0 means bad)

I want to write a condition to check if the flag is 0 or 1 over the 
last 8 minutes , before 4 minutes and after 4 minutes, after 8 minutes

Original table:

```
MONITORID   CREATEDATETIME    Flag
209263      26/3/2019 16:56     1
209262      26/3/2019 16:54     1
209261      26/3/2019 16:52     1
209260      26/3/2019 16:50     1
209259      26/3/2019 16:48     1
209258      26/3/2019 16:46     1
209257      26/3/2019 16:44     1
209256      26/3/2019 16:42     1
209255      26/3/2019 16:40     1
209254      26/3/2019 16:38     1
209253      26/3/2019 16:36     1
209252      26/3/2019 16:34     1
209251      26/3/2019 16:32     1
209250      26/3/2019 16:30     1
209249      26/3/2019 16:28     1
209248      26/3/2019 16:26     1
209247      26/3/2019 16:24     1
209246      26/3/2019 16:22     1
209245      26/3/2019 16:20     1
209244      26/3/2019 16:18     1
```

Final outcome should look like:

```
MONITORID   CREATEDATETIME    Flag  Flag_+4_-4  Flag_+0_-8
209263      26/3/2019 16:56     1       3           5
209262      26/3/2019 16:54     1       4           5
209261      26/3/2019 16:52     1       5           5
209260      26/3/2019 16:50     1       5           5
209259      26/3/2019 16:48     1       5           5
209258      26/3/2019 16:46     1       5           5
209257      26/3/2019 16:44     1       5           5
209256      26/3/2019 16:42     1       5           5
209255      26/3/2019 16:40     1       5           5
209254      26/3/2019 16:38     1       5           5
209253      26/3/2019 16:36     1       5           5
209252      26/3/2019 16:34     1       5           5
209251      26/3/2019 16:32     1       5           5
209250      26/3/2019 16:30     1       5           5
209249      26/3/2019 16:28     1       5           5
209248      26/3/2019 16:26     1       5           5
209247      26/3/2019 16:24     1       5           4
209246      26/3/2019 16:22     1       5           3
209245      26/3/2019 16:20     1       4           2
209244      26/3/2019 16:18     1       3           1
```

The reason for us to comeup with this logic is to see over the last 8 minutes if the it is all good. Then aggregate it to a daily level to show if it was good the whole day.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this problem yourself? Could you please share your attempt(s)? Are time stamps **always** every 2 minute?

Comment: I couldn't implement this logic, yes it is recorded every 2 minutes without fail.

Comment: We love that you're here and we want to help you fix your code rather than write code for you.

Comment: It's fine that you attempts didn't work @Toros91 but it's still important to show us what you did try. It may be that your attempt was very close to the mark. Did you consider using `LAG`, for example? What about `ROWS BETWEEN`?

Comment: yes I understand, thanks for the explanation, I don't have any leads on how to join the tables, so any leads or direction would help me to do research in a better way.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? (Please don't be 2008...)

Comment: @Larnu: Incoming window functions detected

Comment: You know it @GeorgeMenoutis. But means the OP ***needs*** to be on  SQL Server 2012+ (which they really should be, based on the fact that 2008 is about to hit support rock bottom).

Comment: @Larnu: SQL Server 2017

Comment: what?! can you link me to an article about this?

Comment: "I want to write a condition to check if the flag is 0 or 1 over the last 8 minutes , before 4 minutes and after 4 minutes, after 8 minutes" -- Can you explain better (be more explicit) what all this do and your column... are these sum of flags?  Also you provided 0 example of flag with 0 in your example.  Better to cover a wider range of possible values when exposing a problem with data.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/sql-server/sql-server-2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you're after. This uses a conditional aggregate, and the `ROWS BETWEEN` clause to count the number of times `Flag` has the value 1 in the "range" defined. This, however, **requires** that the rows are in 2 minute intervals. if they are not, this will *not* work as you expect:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT V.MONITORID,
           CONVERT(smalldatetime,V.CREATEDATETIME,103) AS CREATEDATETIME,
           Flag
    FROM (VALUES (209263,'26/3/2019 16:56',1),
                 (209262,'26/3/2019 16:54',1),
                 (209261,'26/3/2019 16:52',1),
                 (209260,'26/3/2019 16:50',1),
                 (209259,'26/3/2019 16:48',1),
                 (209258,'26/3/2019 16:46',1),
                 (209257,'26/3/2019 16:44',1),
                 (209256,'26/3/2019 16:42',1),
                 (209255,'26/3/2019 16:40',1),
                 (209254,'26/3/2019 16:38',1),
                 (209253,'26/3/2019 16:36',1),
                 (209252,'26/3/2019 16:34',1),
                 (209251,'26/3/2019 16:32',1),
                 (209250,'26/3/2019 16:30',1),
                 (209249,'26/3/2019 16:28',1),
                 (209248,'26/3/2019 16:26',1),
                 (209247,'26/3/2019 16:24',1),
                 (209246,'26/3/2019 16:22',1),
                 (209245,'26/3/2019 16:20',1),
                 (209244,'26/3/2019 16:18',1)) V(MONITORID, CREATEDATETIME, Flag))
SELECT V.MONITORID,
       V.CREATEDATETIME,
       V.Flag,
       COUNT(CASE V.Flag WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY V.CREATEDATETIME
                                                  ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING) AS [Flag-4+4],
       COUNT(CASE V.Flag WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY V.CREATEDATETIME
                                                  ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [Flag-8+0]
FROM VTE V
ORDER BY V.CREATEDATETIME DESC;
```

Comment: Works like a charm, really sorry for asking such silly question. I really wasted like 1 whole day because I din't know the exact keywords to search for. Thank you so much! I really appreciate your prompt reply! Cheers!

Comment: @Toros91 nothing wrong with not knowing the `ROWS BETWEEN` syntax. It's something that a lot of people seem to have missed since it was introduced in 2012. It is, however, an incredibly useful tool. (Personally, I think there were a great number of window/aggregate functions that were added with 2012.) If this did fix the problem, however, please do mark it as the solution so that future readers know it was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, would do that too.